# How to set the Struts2 Action defined in struts.xml to PortletURL

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, liferay, portlet

Inside the JSP Page I have this for making a AJAX Request within Liferay:

```java
PortletURL portletURL = response.createRenderURL();
portleturl.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
```

I will pass this `portletURL` as a url to the below JQuery function

```jquery
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: portleturl ,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

This is my action mapping inside the `struts.xml` file:

```xml
<action name="helloForm" class="com.action.Struts2Action">
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Now please tell me how do I set the action named `helloForm` to the `portletURL`?

Answer (score 0):

It is common in the code of Liferay. For example, in [this JSP file](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/asset_publisher/view.jsp#L105) a link is created with a parameter defined by

```jsp
<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/asset_publisher/edit_subscription" />
```

(which points to this [action mapping](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml#L272) inside the huge Liferay `struts-config.xml` file).

So, I suppose you just need to add a parameter to your URL in the same way, with the sole difference of doing it with the `PortletURL` object:

```java
PortletURL portletURL = response.createRenderURL();
portleturl.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
portletURL.setParameter("struts_action", "helloForm");
```